# 2 animated image buttons only 1 is working

Tags: javascript, html, button, imagebutton, animated

I'm new to this but I'm sure this is an easy one. I'm trying to setup multiple animated image buttons on my website. I setup two test buttons, but only the second one is working. Both of them works fine by themselves but when I add them together only one works. What am I missing? Thanks in advance.

```
HTML:

<html>
<head>
<title>Default</title><script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
<div align="center"><br>
<a href="url_link"><img style="border: 0px solid ; width: 60px; height:60px;" alt="" src="clickA1.png" id="button1" onmouseover="rollover()" onmouseout="rollout()" onmousedown="down()" onmouseup="rollover()"></a>
</div>
<br />
<div align="center"><br>
<a href="url_link"><img style="border: 0px solid ; width: 60px; height: 60px;" alt="" src="clickB1.png" id="button2" onmouseover="rollover()" onmouseout="rollout()" onmousedown="down()" onmouseup="rollover()"></a>
</div>
<br />
</body></html>


Javascript:

<script>

function rollover () {
document.getElementById ("button1") .src = "clickA2.png"
}
function rollover () {
document.getElementById ("button2") .src = "clickB2.png"
}

function rollout () {
document.getElementById ("button1") .src = "clickA1.png"
}
function rollout () {
document.getElementById ("button2") .src = "clickB1.png"
}

function down () {
document.getElementById ("button1") .src = "clickA3.png"
}
function down () {
document.getElementById ("button2") .src = "clickB3.png"
}

</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You functions are over riding each other. Define a different name for the functions of button2

for example:

```
function rollover () {
  document.getElementById ("button1") .src = "clickA2.png"
}

function rollover2 () {
 document.getElementById ("button2") .src = "clickB2.png"
}
```

Comment: @ceejcast you are welcome. Just set the answer as the right one so that those who see this post in future will know what worked

Answer (score 0):

You have used multiple functions with the same name. In these cases functions written later overwrites the previous ones in the same scope.

A possible way is to include arguments inside your function calls

`<button ... onmousedown="down('button1')" ...></button>`
`<button ... onmousedown="down('button2')" ...></button>`

and handle them inside your function.

`function down (button) {
   document.getElementById (button) .src = "clickB3.png"
}`

Or you can also detect which button was pressed from mousedown event.

Answer (score 0):

You are writing two functions with the same name but different body. The 2nd one replaces the 1st implementation.